# 6 decimal places being rounded up to 4 in MS-Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, decimal, rounding

I've got a textbox which allows the user to enter up to 6 decimal places. This is working, however, when saving (code below), the value is rounded up to 4 decimal places instead and this is how it is saved.

```
sqlupdate = "UPDATE [Products] SET [Product_Description] = @desc , " & _
            "[Unit_Type] = @ut , " & _
            "[RegularPrice] = @pr, " & _
            "[Product_Category_ID] = @catid, " & _
            "[CostPrice] = @costpc, " & _
            "[defVol] = @defvol, [size] = @size " & _
             "WHERE [Base_Code] = @basecode"

 cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlupdate, con, trans)

 Dim decSize As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_size.Text)

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catid", categoryID)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@costpc", costPc)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@defvol", volume)
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@size", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = decSize
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@basecode", txtCode.Text)
```

I've even tried setting the database field to 6 decimal places, but it's not worked. I'm working with Access 1997.

Also, the database is already in a live environment, so if a database change is required, it needs to be done programatically, rather than by going into the database.

These are the field types I'm able to set it to in the database.

[image]

Comment: You're working with Access '97, from more than 20 years ago? Why? Also, check the field size in Access, rounding depends on the max size of the decimal.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Wasn't my project originally, the original dev built it using Access '97

Comment: Also, there is no field size setting in Access '97, at least not for Currency data types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type of that field seems to be *Currency*, as it is the only data type of the JET database V3.5 (that used by Access 97) that will round to four decimals.

So double-check the table's field type.

Comment: What data type should it be, in that case? Number removes all decimal places totally.

Comment: In JET 3.5 your only option would be _Double_. Decimal was first introduced with JET 4.0. The alternativ "option" would be a _scaled_ Currency: Multiply with 100 when saving and dividing by 100 when reading.

Comment: So, in the code use a Double variable and insert this into the database? Otherwise, Double isn't a data type that can be used in the table design.

Comment: Using a Double hasn't fixed it, the value is still rounded to 4 DP.

Comment: _Double isn't a data type that can be used in the table design._ - don't know what you mean. It is. And you probably also must adjust your code reflect that as well.

Comment: See my edit, I've added the screenshot of all the possible data types for the field. I've also changed the sampled code from Decimal to Double.

Comment: Select Number, then Double.

Comment: Using `"ALTER TABLE [Products] ALTER COLUMN [size] DOUBLE(11, 6)"`, I get a syntax error, but without the (11, 6) parameters it works fine. Why are the parameters breaking it?

Comment: Because Double is a _floating point_ data type like Single is.